# Install Custom Tool Kit for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp

This may be a stupid question for you guys but it's kind a big deal for newbie like me so i really grateful if you could guide me how to install, import [this](https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit) tool into my UWP project. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it. Screenshots from VS2017RC (but it's very similar in 2015)

[image: Manage the NuGet packages for the project]

Search for "MyToolkit"

[image: Select the Toolkit and Toolkit.Extended]

Install the top two options seen in the results here (MyToolkit and MyToolkit.Extended)
The Extended package includes most of the UWP controls

Select OK if you see this prompt.

[image: Select OK if you see this prompt]

You can now use the classes, etc. in the toolkit within your project. :)

Comment: Nice answer. It will be helpful if you also create this as documentation there.